# Loop Efficiency Comparison

Tags: android, performance, loops, arraylist

Which of these is more efficient? :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int a : list){
   log.i(tag, a + "");
}

SparseIntArray list2 = new SparseIntArray();
int count = list2.size();
for(int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
   log.i(tag, list2.get(j) + "");
}
```

Or, is there a faster way to read the contents of the list?

Comment: check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach

Comment: Would the second one even work if there are gaps between indexes?  The docs say `list2.size()` returns the number of key/value pairs, not the highest index.  Meaning, if your map had two entries ({100=>100, 200=>200}), wouldn't you never see them...?

Comment: @cHao correct, it will not necessarily iterate over all the values (unless previous code was written that way, which is not enforceable), and additionally, any missing keys in range will just return 0, meaning log.i(tag, "0") may be called a lot.

Comment: @cHao  , i know  , just a example , i default it is no gaps inside

Comment: @Chet, yeah .i know if the size is the highest value , it will call too much

Comment: easily fixable with int key = cs.keyAt(j); // so you *can* iterate on SparseIntArray

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Efficiency, in this case, is irrelevant, since those two do completely different things.

I think you realize that your `ArrayList` example iterates through all the elements of the array-list.

What you don't realize is that your `SparseIntArray` example does *not* iterate through all the elements of the sparse-integer-array, because the keys of a sparse-integer-array do *not* range from zero to array-size-minus-one. Rather, its keys are arbitrary integers. A sparse-integer-array has as much in common, interface-wise, with `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` as with `ArrayList<Integer>`.

(This, by the way, relates to a general rule of software design: it is better for your code to be *correct* than *efficient*. You can always take correct, clean code and find ways to improve its performance; but it's very hard to take fast, buggy code and find ways to make it correct.)

Comment: +1 for answering first and mentioning similarity with HashMap.

Comment: @ruakh , i think so , thanks for your comment , i think in my case use arraylist as normal is better .

Answer (score 2):

For-each loops like your first example are almost always preferable when you don't need an index variable for other reasons.

Edit: ArrayLists would iterate more efficiently (in your example, repeatedly calling "get") than SparseIntArray because lookups are constant time as opposed to logarithmic time. This will depend a bit on your use case though--if your keys are sparse then SparseIntArray will save you a lot of memory space.

I would point out that the SparseIntArray can have gaps in the indicies, meaning that looping over every value between 0 and Size is not only inefficient, but it will also return 0 for every missing index, which is probably not your intended behavior.

Comment: Actually, a lookup in `SparseIntArray` requires *logarithmic* time, since it uses binary search. And for every "missing index" inside the range `[0, size)`, there is an *extra* index *outside* that range, that the loop will never reach, because `size` is the number of elements, rather than being related to the greatest index in the array. (See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html, http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/util/SparseIntArray.java.htm.)

Comment: @ruakh oh , thanks , i just miss that point , thank you very much XD .

Comment: @ruakh Very interesting. I had only guessed at implementation. Considering SparseIntArray is supposed to be more efficient than HashMap, but it actually has higher algorithmic time.

Comment: It has higher algorithmic time, but much less overhead (no boxing and unboxing of `int` to `Integer`, no series of calculations to distribute hash-codes properly, and so on). So while there's necessarily some size above which a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` will perform better, I'd expect `SparseIntArray` to be faster up to (if I may make a random guess) somewhere between 100 and 2000 elements. This also depends, of course, on how the map is used. Modifications of a `SparseIntArray` are comparatively quite expensive (since they involve insertion into a sorted array), while conversely, iteration

Comment: over a `SparseIntArray` is inherently cheaper (since the elements are densely packed into arrays).

Comment: @ruakh thanks for explaining! that would be my guess. The source you linked to is very simple and clearly would avoid a lot of the overhead.

Answer (score 2):

**SparseIntArrays** map integers to integers. Unlike a normal array of integers, there can be gaps in the indices. It is intended to be more efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Integers.

[Read More](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)